# Consider $X=C[0,1]$ with its usual sup-norm topology.Let $S=\{f\in X :\int _0^1f\neq 0\}$.Is the set connected?

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

Consider $X=C[0,1]$  with its usual sup-norm topology.Let $S=\{f\in X :\int _0^1f\neq 0\}$.Is the set  connected?

I tried to conclude from the path connectedness of $S$ .But $S$ is not path connected

Comment: Hint: Consider the linear operator $f\mapsto \int_0^1f$. What can you say about it? Can you deduce an answer to your question from that?

Answer (score 2):

If you consider real-valued functions, the set is split is two halves by the kernel of the functional $\varphi:f\longmapsto\int_0^1f$.

More explicitly, 
$$
S=\varphi^{-1}(-\infty,0)\cup\varphi^{-1}(0,\infty)
$$
is a disjoint union of open sets.

In the complex-valued case, $S$ is path connected.

Comment: yes i have got it.thanks

Comment: In the complex valued case, the set is path connected.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I added a non-answer below, since the comment was too long.

Comment: Good point, thank. Initially I couldn't see what was wrong with my argument. Now I see that you can have $\int f\ne0$ even with $\text{Re}\int f=0$.

Comment: $\phi$ is linear but why is it continuous?

Comment: $|\phi(f)| \le \|f\|_\infty$, hence $\|\phi\| \le 1$ (in fact, since $\phi(x \mapsto 1) = 1$, we have $\|\phi\| = 1$).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but wouldn't fit in a comment. It is a response to Martin.

Suppose we have $f,g \in S$. Then $z f \in S$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. Since $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is path connected, there is some path $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(0) = 1, \gamma(1) = {\phi(g) \over \phi(f)}$ and $\gamma$ does not pass through zero. Then the path  $\gamma \cdot f$ 'changes' $f$ to $f'={\phi(g) \over \phi(f)} f$, and $\phi(f') = \phi(g)$. Now consider the path $\eta(\lambda) = (1-\lambda) f' + \lambda g$, with $\lambda \in [0,1]$. We see that $\phi(\eta(\lambda)) = \phi(g)$ for all $\lambda$ and $\eta(1) = g$.

Comment: Sir one question ,in Martin's answer why is $\phi$ continuous.We know a linear functional on a finite dimensional NLS is continuous.But $C[a,b]$ is not finite dimensional